# No buffer space available (tcp.cpp:69) when setting SNDBUF and RCVBUF ZeroMQ, golang, MacOSX

Tags: sockets, go, zeromq

I have zeromq: stable 4.1.4 installed using brew on MacOSX and have written a simple PUB/SUB program to test zeromq.  But when I run the sample program using flags --bufsize > 5 (to use a buffer of size > 5MB) (go run go_zmq_pubsub.go --bufsize=6); it throws the following exception:

No buffer space available (tcp.cpp:69)
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7fff9911c286 m=0
signal arrived during cgo execution

Below is the program I used to test the zeromq4.x

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "time"
)

var _ = fmt.Println

func main(){
    var port int
    var bufsize int
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 7676, "server's zmq tcp port")
    flag.IntVar(&bufsize, "bufsize", 0, "socket kernel buffer size")

    flag.Parse();

    publisher, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.PUB)
    if(err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //set publisher kernel transmit buffer size
    //convert into bytes
    if err := publisher.SetSndbuf(bufsize * 1000000); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer publisher.Close()
    publisher.Bind("tcp://*:" + strconv.Itoa(port))

    //SETUP subscriber
    subscriber, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.SUB)
    if(err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //set subscriber kernel receive buffer size
    if err := subscriber.SetRcvbuf(bufsize * 1000000); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer subscriber.Close()
    subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:" + strconv.Itoa(port))
    subscriber.SetSubscribe("")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    idx := 0

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        //start streaming messages
        ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ticker.C:
                    _, err = publisher.Send("PKG:"+strconv.Itoa(idx), 0)

                    idx++;

                    if(err != nil) {
                        log.Error(err)
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
    }(&wg)


    //receiver
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        go func(){
            for {
                payload, err := subscriber.Recv(0)
                _ = payload

                if err != nil {
                    log.Error(err)
                    break
                }

                //now sending into worker pool
                log.Info("RECEIVE:" + payload)
            }
        }()
    }(&wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

On Centos7 with lib-zeromq built from source, the above code works without problem.

Not sure if it's due to libzeromq or the OS itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A buffer size of > 5MB is pointless. Anything beyond the bandwidth-delay product of the link concerned is wasted space.

Moderate your requirements.

Comment: Hi, in my real application, I have an UDP listener which read UDP packages from multiple high-load producers. For now, as soon as UDP packages arrive, I publish them via zeromq and have multiple subscribers/worker process which process the data. The traffic is not constant but can be "peak" at some points. If the buffer size is small and consumers are slow at that time, packages might be dropped silently. I am thinking of having buffer size of around 100Mb, not sure if it's too much?